# Infinite Scroll + foreach ->echo only once

Tags: php, foreach, infinite-scroll

I'm using infinite scroll on one of my pages, combined with a foreach-loop.
My -relevant- code:

```
<div id="container" class="infinite-scroll span12"> 
   <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?> 
      <div class="element">
         <?php echo $this->Html->image($item); ?> 
      </div> 
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Scrolling further down loads the infinite-scroll plugin. The #container gets updated.

**I'd now like to display one image only on the beginning of the first page.**

***Any idea how I could implement this?***

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just display `$items[0]`.

Comment: then it shows on page:2 and page:3 etc. at the beginning.
I only want it on page:1

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the first element, then there is no need for a foreach loop, just echo out the single element:

```
<div id="container" class="infinite-scroll span12"> 
    <div class="element"><?=$this->Html->image($items[0])?></div> 
</div>
```

If you want a random item to be shown, then get one random number from the array and use that:

```
<div id="container" class="infinite-scroll span12"> 
    <div class="element"><?=$this->Html->image(rand(0,sizeof($items)-1))?></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it, but the item will show on all pages at the beginning aswell.
So scrolling down would repeat the image that is only supposed to show up at the first page.

Comment: Then you need to keep track of what items you have showed and echo out the next item, you haven't shown yet.

Comment: ..and how can i keep track if the image when it's not called from the database. -i.e. not part of the items-array. any idea?

Comment: Create another array where you store ID's of showed images and check that array, before displaying new ones.